# Using Nearest Neighbor search on an n element object

Tags: python, algorithm, search, nearest-neighbor

I am looking for a way to use Nearest Neighbor search on an n element object in python. I want to have my parent object and then order the others based on nearest elements to it from nearest to farthest. so can example would be:

```
Parents: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

and the other objects say

```
O1 = 1, 2, 2, 1, 2
O2 = 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
O3 = 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

so I would want it to return O1 as most relevant and O2 as least relevant.

So not sure what packages and algorithm to use.

Comment: What should it do for sets like:
`Parents: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1`
`O1: 1, 1, 1, 1, 6`
`O2: 2, 2, 2, 2, 2`

Comment: Somehow I would have to define rules as to the closeness between the two. Maybe like the average difference between the two? (average as in the difference between each element divided by 5) then sort by that? in which case those two would be tied and would not matter the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting point:

```
def get_nearest(src, others):
    nearest = None
    nearest_dist = float("inf") # Some huge number that everything is less than
    for i in others:
        dist = metric(src, i) # But what is metric?
        if dist < nearest_dist:
            nearest = i
            nearest_dist = dist

    return nearest
```

This returns the closest match, according to some function `metric` that takes in two objects and returns some distance value.

So how do you define `metric`? Well, that depends. There's several ways of doing it, and you need to choose the one that most fits what data you're working with and what constitutes two objects being "close".

For your list of numbers, you can try selecting the object with the least average difference between corresponding values:

```
def metric(a, b):
    s = 0
    for x, y in zip(a,b):
        s += abs(x-y)
    return s / len(a)
```

You can also do something more complex, like the root-mean-square average of the differences, or applying an exponential function to the differences so that outliers will stand out more. It all depends on what you want to do with the data.